# Determine number of columns in isotope (masonry)

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to determine the number of columns I have displayed on various viewport sizes. I found this *this.masonry.cols* on http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html#helper_methods

I haven't managed to get anything out of that though. Does anyone have experience using it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question looking for the same thing, and thankfully the answer is on the page you linked to.

`this.masonry.cols` is an internal variable. It's there for the functions inside isotope to use... So if you want to use it yourself, all you need to do is extend isotope.

### Example - display number of columns in the console

Assuming you're using the jQuery method, do the following before you start using isotope:

```
$.extend( $.Isotope.prototype, {
  myMethod : function() { console.log(this.masonry.cols) }
});
```

Then, once you initialise isotope on a container element, you can simple run your new function like so:

> $container.isotope('myMethod');

That will output the number of columns in the console log.

Does that help you?
If you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve I can help you further.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this answer, I searched exactly this solution for fixing centering. If you are using directly Masonry, the code is: jQuery.extend( Masonry.prototype, {                  
  yourMethod : function() {
   return this.cols; 
  }
 });